# How to calculate the above double integral?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Suppose that $(X_1, X_2)$ has joint pdf $f(x_1,x_2)=24x_1x_2$ with $1>x_1, x_2>0$ and $x_1+x_2<1$.

(1) Find $P(X_1<X_2)$.

(2) Find the marginal of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I can get the probability by the area of the graph, which is the fourth of the square (=1/4). I try to calculate this integral by formula:

$$
\int\int_C (24x_1x_2)dx_1dx_2
$$
where $C=\{1>x_1, x_2>0, x_1+x_2<1, x_1<x_2\}$.

But how to calculate the above double integral and marginal integral?

---

For the first double integral,

$$
\int\int_C (24x_1x_2)dx_2dx_2=\int_0^{1/2}dx_1 \int_{x_2=1-x_1}^{x_1} (24x_1x_2)dx_2=12\int_0^{1/2}(2x_1^2-x_1)dx_1
$$
But I got $1/2$ but not $1/4$...

---

For (b), the marginal of $X_2$ is given by

$$
f_{X_2}(x)=\int_0^1 f(x_1, x_2)dx_1=
$$
I am not sure why the above integral is equal to $$\int_0^{1-x_2} (24x_1x_2)dx_1$$

Comment: $$
\int\int_C (24x_1x_2)dx_2dx_2=\int_0^{1/2}dx_1 \int_{x_2=1-x_1}^{x_1} (24x_1x_2)dx_2=12\int_0^{1/2}(x_1-2x_1^2)dx_1=\frac12,
$$which is not surprising since $P(X_1<X_2)=P(X_2<X_1).$ Why did you think "I can get the probability by the area of the graph"?

Comment: What is your attempt for the 2nd question?

Comment: @AnneBauval If we draw the support of this integral $C=\{x_1>0, x_2>0, x_1+x_2<1, x_1<x_2\}$, the area of this support should be 1/4 but not 1/2. But why the integral is not the area of the support?

Comment: @AnneBauval I update my approach for (b). Can you please see my question? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Anne Bauval's comment answered the question.

Comment: It is the integral of $1$ which is the area of the support. Not the integral of $24x_1x_2.$

Comment: For (b), your are not computing the correct integral(s). Review your definition of marginal.

Comment: @AnneBauval Do you mean $f_{X_2}(x)=\int_{R}f(x_1,x_2)dx_1$?

Comment: If your $R$ means $\Bbb R,$ this equality is wrong as well. The RHS must depend on $x.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry for the typo, I mean $f_{X_2}(x_2)=\int_R f(x_1, x_2)dx_1$. Yes, that $R$ is the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $$\iint_C (24x_1x_2)\,dx_{\color\red1}dx_2=\int_0^{1/2}\,dx_1\int_{x_2=1-x_1}^{x_1} (24x_1x_2)\,dx_2=12\int_0^{1/2}(x_1-2x_1^2)\,dx_1=\frac12,$$
which is not surprising since $P(X_1<X_2)=P(X_2<X_1).$

(2) The ["marginal" *density*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#Marginal_probability_density_function) of $X_2$ is
$$f_{X_2}(x_2)=\int_{0<x_1,x_2\atop x_1+x_2<1}24x_1x_2\, dx_1=24x_2{\bf1}_{(0,1)}(x_2)\int_0^{1-x_2}x_1\,dx_1=12x_2(1-x_2)^2{\bf1}_{(0,1)}(x_2),$$
where ${\bf1}_{(0,1)}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the interval $(0,1).$ You can check that $\int_0^112x_2(1-x_2)^2\,dx_2=1.$